# Display recently viewed pages and an image for that page in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

So title basically sums it up, how would I go about doing something like this?

I want a logged in user to have their own "logged in page" that they can view products that they have recently viewed and then suggest other products that they might like to view in the future.

Any ideas? Google literally has nothing on doing this with CakePHP.

I am so lost for what to do and this is for an assignment due tomorrow night.

Answer (score 1):

You need to created a database table to records users activity. Mean, you need to save what product are browsing by users and you can show them this in next.